# Single Activity Backstack for multiple activities

Tags: android

i have activities. A, B, C.

1. A ----> B when app is started.  B and C are activties that communicate frequently.  i select a single or double date range values in the Activity C.
2. Now from B ---> C, i select a double date range through StartActivityForResult
3. C ---> B
4. i decide to go back to C and select a single range value this time (B -> C) via StartActivityForResult
5. C ---> B
6. i press the back on Activity B to return to A (B --> A) but it goes back to B when the double date range was selected.

How do i stop this. I have tried using  the flag Single_Top when going from B --> C and Reorder_To_Front when going from C --> B but it's not working..

Comment: which component do you use for date range selection?

Comment: The transition is confusing.Can you explain clearly!

Comment: @MocialovBoris not sure what you mean exactly? but i use intents for everything.

Comment: why don't you use finish() instead of using intent every time . when ever you are coming back use finish() .no need to  create intent  every time onback.

Comment: @KingCobraa  yes i use StartActivityForResult() when going back to B. i will try to explain it more clearly.

Comment: @KingCobraa sorry i meant when going to C from B. I have edited my question.

Comment: @Nargis i have edited my question. hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @Nargis i think only you can understand ,what does he want to say.

Comment: The approach which is mentioned by @KingCobraa will 100% work...